# How Map Multiple related Entities to one DTO Object using AutoMapper EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have three related Entities in my blazor application **Opportunity**, **AppUser** and **AssignedOpportunity**, What I want to achieve is to map **Opportunity** and **AppUser** to a DTO Object **ReturnAssignedOpportunityDTO** which has similar fields as the entities, using **AutoMapper**, but am not sure how to do that, below are the entities

```
 public partial class AssignedOpportunity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OpportunityID")]
    public string OpportunityID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Opportunity opportunity { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
}
```

The opportunity

```
 public partial class Opportunity
{
    public Opportunity()
    {           
        AssignedOpportunities= new HashSet<AssignedOpportunity>();
    }
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string OpportunityName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public double EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNeed { get; set; }
    public double RealValue { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string ReasonStatus { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<AssignedOpportunity> AssignedOpportunities { get; set; }
}
```

AppUser Class

```
 public partial class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        AssignedOpportunities = new HashSet<AssignedOpportunity>();
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string LGA { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssignedOpportunity> AssignedOpportunities { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the DTO Object I want to map to.

```
 public class ReturnOpportunitiesDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OpportunityID { get; set; }
    public string OpportunityName { get; set; }
    public double EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNeed { get; set; }
    public double RealValue { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }      
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my query to fetch the records

```
 var result = await _context.AssignedOpportunities.Include(o => o.opportunity).
                ThenInclude(a => a.User).
                Where(a=>a.UserID==UserID.ToString()).ToListAsync();
            return result;
```

This is how i usually setup Map Profile

```
 public AssignArtisanProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AssignedOpportunity, ReturnOpportunities>();
    }
```

But since I want to map multiple entities, how do I include the other entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario is just another example of flattening a complex object. You have properties in child objects, which you want to bring to the ground level, while still leveraging AutoMapper mapping capabilities. If only you could reuse other maps from app user and opportunity when mapping from assigned opportunity to the DTO... Well, there is a method called `IncludeMembers()` (see the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers)) that exists precisely for such case. It allows you to reuse the configuration in the existing maps for the child types:

```cs
config.CreateMap<AssignedOpportunity, ReturnOpportunitiesDTO>()
    .IncludeMembers(source => source.opportunity, source => source.User);
config.CreateMap<Opportunity, ReturnOpportunitiesDTO>();
config.CreateMap<AppUser, ReturnOpportunitiesDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.UserFullName,
        options => options.MapFrom(source =>
            string.Join(
                " ",
                source.FirstName,
                source.MiddleName,
                source.LastName)));
```

Usage:

```cs
var mappedDtos = mapper.Map<List<ReturnOpportunitiesDTO>>(assignedOpportuniesFromDatabase);
```